# How to separate authentication logic for two different admin panel in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I have been implementing two admin panels. One for the superuser and another one for the let's say seller admin.I can separate logic via Django's in-built groups and permission modules, but i need different wordings and custom designs for that two different admin panels. Structure of my 2 admin panels are below.

1. This is the usual way of django,

urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(modelname)
```

So,admin panel logic is completely fine. Issue is to separate the seller and admin with each other. So, i created different seller panel with this,

2. admin.py

   > Custom admin panel
   >
   > ```
   > from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
   > class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
   >     pass
   > myadmin = MyAdminSite(name="myadmin")
   > myadmin.register(User)
   > ```

urls.py

```
url(r'^seller-panel/', include(myadmin.urls))
```

So,here we have two different urls for the two different admin panel.By this i achieved different admin looks and urls. Main problem is to differentiate the login between this two admin panels. Only Problem is

> "Admin can login into seller admin panel and seller can login into
>   superuser admin panel"

Can we implement this logic by two custom admin logins ? or Groups and permission via is_staff option is the only way?

Comment: Have you tried grappelli custom dashboard ? http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html#custom-dashboard

Comment: Yes,by using grappelli or in django we can manage custom dashboard without third parties, but needed custom authentication for both.

Answer (score 0):

Since your underlying goal is to reuse the admin views and logic for the `seller` type users, and you are probably going to want many more custom views and features for these users, I would suggest a different approach.

Instead of making two different admin types with different login pages, make the `seller` users a regular users with login and corresponding pages in the standard views like usual. And there (in the non admin part of the website) you might want to reuse some of the admin logic and templates.

Comment: hmm, that was the idea but since there will be sensitive data i can not use this structure.And the default admin change list,actions etc can not be used for that.